# Wordcloud of own list

Tags: word-cloud

I wanted to create a word cloud of countries according to their GDP. I need to extract this information from my own dataset and not from Mathematica. So I made a list of countries and GDPs:

```
DataACT0Combination = Transpose[{DataACT1, DataACT3}]
 {{"Afghanistan", 1919.}, {"Albania", 11840.}, {"Algeria", 
      15027.}, {"Andorra", "-"}, {"Angola",6844.}, {"AntiguaBarbuda", 
  "-"}, {"Argentina", 20048.}, {"Armenia", 8621.}, {"Australia", 
  48899.}, {"Austria", 48005.}, {"Azerbaijan", 17439.}, {"Bahamas", 
  24555.}, {"Bahrain", 50704.}, {"Bangladesh", 3891.}, {"Barbados", 
  17100.}, {"Belarus", 18000.}}]
```

Unfortunately Mathematica won't allow me to do a `WordCloud [DataACT0Combination ]`. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Some of the weights you are using are `"-"` when they should be positive numbers.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = {{"Afghanistan", 1919.}, {"Albania", 11840.}, {"Algeria", 
    15027.}, {"Andorra", "-"}, {"Angola", 6844.}, {"AntiguaBarbuda", 
    "-"}, {"Argentina", 20048.}, {"Armenia", 8621.}, {"Australia", 
    48899.}, {"Austria", 48005.}, {"Azerbaijan", 17439.}, {"Bahamas", 
    24555.}, {"Bahrain", 50704.}, {"Bangladesh", 3891.}, {"Barbados", 
    17100.}, {"Belarus", 18000.}};
```

`WordCloud`  cannot handle data with non-numeric weights (such as `{"Andorra", "-"}`), so we need to pre-process input data to remove pairs with non-numeric weights:

```
WordCloud[DeleteCases[{_, Except[_?NonNegative]}]@data]
```

[image]